# Make formatArg in string resource bold Andoid

Tags: android, spannablestring, formatted-text

I have String resource with format argument *%s*

`<string name="string_name">Hello Mr. %s. I want to ...</string>`

This string resource is localized, so has different length depending on locale and has to be in one TextView

I want to make *formatArg* **%s** bold style

I've tried html tag
  `<string name="string_name">Hello Mr. <b>%s</b>. I want to ...</string>`

I've tried annotation tag
  `<string name="string_name">Hello Mr. <annotation style="bold">%s</annotation>. I want to ...</string>`

I've created SpannableString and tried to set Span to this annotation

And no any effect to string argument after I set text to TextView

`tvDescription.setText(getString(R.string.string_name, "formatArg"));`

Is there a way to set style to the string argument in formatted string resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i style the message of an AlertDialog:

```
Spanned htmlAsSpanned = Html.fromHtml("Some html tags are working in here<br /><br />
<b>this is bold text</b>");
```

Edit: Or maybe [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML) is what you are looking for.
Their example is this:

```
String text = getString(R.string.welcome_messages, "Roko Spark", 5);
Spanned styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);

textView.setText(styledText);
```

> In this formatted string, a `<b>` element is added. Notice that the
>   opening bracket is HTML-escaped, using the `&lt;` notation.

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have &lt;b>%2$d new messages&lt;/b>.</string>
```

Comment: I've tried html tags, but I have to use string resources and problem is in format argument %s. I can't make it bold style.
I know how to set style to some part of string or text, but when it comes to format argument and string resources any of these methods work

Comment: Thank you @einUsername. That worked. I haven't noticed that note in documentation about format string and html styling